# Heap corruption when deleting ptr

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, heap-corruption

I have the following class:

```
class Label : public Object
{
public:
    Label ();
    ~Label ();

    void create (const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const wchar_t* text);
    void destroy ();

private:
    unsigned int x, y;
    wchar_t* text;

    void draw (HDC hdc);
    void confirmed (ObjectManager* m);
};
```

With the following code:

```
Label::Label ()
{
    type = LABEL;
    text = NULL;
}

Label::~Label ()
{
    destroy ();
}

void Label::create (const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const wchar_t* text)
{
    unsigned int len = wcslen (text);

    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->text = new wchar_t[len];
    wcscpy (this->text, text);
}

void Label::destroy ()
{
    if (text) {
        delete[] text;
        text = NULL;
    }
    if (m) {
        m->remove (this);
        m = NULL;
    }
}

void Label::draw (HDC hdc)
{
    if (text)
        TextOut (hdc, x, y, text, wcslen (text));
}

void Label::confirmed (ObjectManager* m)
{
    this->m = m;
}
```

When exiting the application Visual Studio reports a heap corruption. I called "create" first, then "confirmed" is called, then "draw" is called and finally the deconstructor is called. The text is initialized correct, so I don't know what the problem is in this code. Could someone explain what is wrong? The heap corruption happens when "delete[] text" is called.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi calling delete will not de-allocate the string. Because a string is an array of characters and you have to call "delete []" in order to de-allocate it.

Comment: @armanali, right. I didn't look closely at what Ruben allocated. My mistake.

Comment: Please declare a private copy constructor and assignment operator or derive from a class that does to ensure you are not copying a `Label` object anywhere. The default implementation will not copy correctly as it stands now, resulting in a double free.

Comment: @Ruben 1) Why didn't you just use `std::wstring text;` in your class definition instead of `wchar_t* text`?  If you did that, then you don't have these issues.   2) There is no need to test for `text` being NULL in the destructor.  Calling `delete[]` on a NULL pointer is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wcslen - returns number of char not including \0

```
unsigned int len = wcslen (text);
this->text = new wchar_t[len + 1];
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcslen/

Comment: Indeed, the corruption occurs, because the linked list of the memory allocation is overwritten full or partially by the `(wchar_t)0`; there is also the safe version of `wcscpy` but it works only for arrays whose size is known - the size of memory allocated for bare pointers isn't.